# Как изменить класс не называя его

Tags: java, ооп

Есть класс `Cars`

```
package sample.cars;

public class Cars {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Car chevrolet = new Car();
    }
}
```

И класс `Car`

```
package sample.cars;

public class Car {
    //Как сделать так чтобы можно было не называть класс при создании объекта
    class Motor {
         public boolean isElectro = false;
    }

}
```

И мне не нужно называть вложенный класс внутри метода `main`. А просто обращаться к классу `Motor` по самому названию класса т.е. так `chevrolet.Motor.isElectro`

Comment: `static class Motor {`?

Comment: и что? это никак не менят проблему.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никак. Если есть объект, то у него должен быть и тип. Безымянных классов не бывает.

Можно сделать так: https://ideone.com/kLiZPn

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Car chevrolet = new Car();
    System.out.println(chevrolet.Motor.isElectro);
  }
}

class Car {
  static class Motor {
     public boolean isElectro = false;
  }

  public Motor Motor = new Motor();
}
```

Но замечу, что в джаве принято писать поля и методы с маленькой буквы, т. е. не `chevrolet.Motor.isElectro`, а `chevrolet.motor.isElectro`. А ещё принято использовать геттеры и сеттеры, но это к вопросу вообще не относится.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант chevrolet.**m**otor.isElectro

```
public class Cars {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car chevrolet = new Car();
        System.out.println(chevrolet.motor.isElectro);
    }
}

public class Car {

    public Motor motor = new Motor();

     class Motor {
         public boolean isElectro = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Чем отличается от моего ответа, кроме отсутствия static у класса?

Comment: Ваш вариант ничем неплох, но, мне кажется, что в рамках контекста, объект двигатель без объекта  машины существовать не может.